# rails 4 update user profile by button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

hy, i'm trying to update a single field in a user resouce. The field to update is 'locale', it is a string type.

i have triend with a form and it works:

```
 <%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
       <%= f.select :locale, [['En', 'en'], ['It', 'it']] %>
       <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

now i'm trying to update the same field using a link or a button:

```
 <%= current_user.locale = 'fr'  %>

 <%= button_to "update" ,current_user,method: :patch %>

 <%= button_to "update" ,user_path(current_user),method: :patch %>
```

but none of this work.

the problem is the request, infact the web server doesn't recive the current_user parameters:

```
 {"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"7X6QdD4DGxsXaETT86/8Ut4xyuOICaxirs4IjmZl7jY=",
 "locale"=>"en",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

There is no current_users parameters.

i have tried with the link_to but the problem is the same:

```
<%= link_to "update", current_user ,method: :patch %>
```

I have no idea. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you don't get the parameter sent back to server is the expected one since you don't use a form.

In order to pass the parameter back you have to:

1. use a form (as you did) or
2. pass the parameter in the url of the button: `button_to 'update', user_path(param_name: 'param_value')`

In the second case, you will have to search for the appropriate parameter in your action, ex `params[:param_name]`